# Query HTML stored in Var with Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I will first explain what I'm trying to do then I will explain why just in case you get bored of reading the whole scenario.

Basically I have some HTML markup stored in a variable I now need to a wait to access the different elements within the variable. For example:

```
var markUp = "<h3>h3 tag</h3><p>paragraph tag</p>";
```

What I need to know is if there is a way for me to query the variable to retrieve say the h3 tag, in a similar way you would use the query function ? I have seen some other practices where people append the var to a hidden div then query the div. I would prefer to avoid this but if that is the only way I will proceed.

I have come across this problem whilst developing a drag and drop application, on drop i use a custom creator function to change the items structure once it is dropped.

If further explanation is needed please say, thanks advance Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dojo._toDom` to create a DOM fragment from your string.

```
var markup = "<h3>h3 tag</h3><p>paragraph tag</p><p>another paragraph</p>";
var domFragment = dojo._toDom(markup);

dojo.query("p", domFragment).forEach(function(element,i) {
    console.debug(element.innerHTML);
});
```

The underscore prefix in `_toDom` means that it's a "private" member method of `dojo`. Normally, it's bad practice to use these as if they were public (like I do here). However, in the case of `_toDom` I believe it's generally considered acceptable, and according to [this trac entry](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/13103), it sounds like it'll be made public in the next version.

Comment: wow thanks Frode hav'nt come across this method before sounds like exactly what I need. Will try this, this evening thanks alot !!!

Comment: Hi Frode seems like a really sill question but I am having a problem appending items from the _toDom Method. I try the following -  var newElem = dojo.query("h3", markUp); But when I append to the dom it just shows [object HTMLHeadingElement] instead of the actual HTML - any suggestions ?

Comment: @jonathan p, how are you appending it to the DOM? When you convert it into a DOM object with `_toDom`, you can't insert it as if it were text. So you can't do `somDiv.innerHTML = newElem;`, you have to do `someDiv.appendChild(newElem);` (or use `dojo.place`).

Comment: lol thanks Frode I consider myself schooled thank you very much.